# Help with a surface of delay differential equations

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, difference-equations, delay-differential-equations

This question is difficult for me to phrase, as it's very much outside of my mathematical purview. This is a question which intersects directly with my research, but as I work predominantly in difference equations, this is something I'm sure I haven't seen before--though I bet many of you fine people may have seen something like it. Now, I have tagged this question to do with delay differential equations, but it's not exactly a DDE.

**BIG DISCLAIMER:** Every function is analytic in this post, we are therefore only looking for analytic solutions.

Let's start by defining an evolving surface:

$$
F(y,\varphi_1,\varphi_2,\varphi_3) = 0\\
$$

So the surface is written as $(\varphi_1,\varphi_2,\varphi_3) \in \Phi(y) \subset \mathbb{R}^3$. The derivatives in all variables of $F$ are non-zero. And choosing any $\varphi_j$, we can assume that $\frac{\partial \varphi_j}{\partial y} \neq 0$.

Now, for my purposes, we can assume this surface is planar (The actual surface looks planar enough and $y\to\infty$ makes it planar), so that:

$$
\begin{align}
\varphi_3(y) &= C(y) + \rho_1(y) \varphi_1(y) + \rho_2(y)\varphi_2(y)\\
&= C(y) + \frac{\partial \varphi_3}{\partial \varphi_1} \varphi_1 + \frac{\partial \varphi_3}{\partial \varphi_2}\varphi_2
\end{align}
$$

Here, we only ask that $\varphi_3$ is analytic for $y > Y > 0$. I am mostly interested with:

$$
\begin{align}
C(y) &\sim -\frac{1}{\log(y)}\\
\rho_1(y) &\sim y^{-c}\,\,\text{for some}\,\,c > 0\\
\rho_2(y) &\sim 1+\frac{1}{y}\\
\end{align}
$$

Now, I am going to make the following restriction:

$$
\varphi_2(y+1) = \varphi_3(y)\\
$$

So the evolving surface looks like:

$$
\varphi_3(y) = C(y) + \rho_1(y) \varphi_1(y) + \rho_2(y)\varphi_3(y-1)\\
$$

One can show that $\varphi_j(y) \to 0$ for each $j=1,2,3$. This first order difference equation is solvable, but it's a pretty ugly solution we do not need to get at the root of the question. Which is, how would one describe the evolution of paths $\varphi_1(y) \subset \mathbb{R}^3$? This is what I mean when I say it is a delay differential equation of sorts, but it involves the evolution of a planar surface.

Now we can expect $\varphi_1(y) \to 0$ and that it goes relatively fast, say $y^{-b}$. As this is the bare minimum the compounded decay of $\rho_1$ contributes. But, we must be sure that it satisfies the differential equation/difference equation in question.

So, my question, in earnest heart:

> Does anyone have any resources which relate to the above theory?